# How would we manage user licenses if we developer an OEM Embedded App

Tags: partner

1. Does Salesforce have/offer a tool/App to help OEM/Embedded partners track and manage their user licensees, similar to the License Manager App that is available to ISV Partners? If so, please direct me to the details.
2. With an OEM App, each customer has their own instance, correct? Does this mean that we would have the ability to support multiple different integrations for every single instance/customer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1.Even for OEM apps you should be getting the LMA app to manage and provision license .You will get a business org where you can have the LMA installed

2.Thats correct every customer will have an instance with SFDC License which will be sold with your OEM app installed .You can design your code in a way so that integration points are configurable and app logic is generic enough to support all your business need .

End users can’t develop applications or extend applications by creating custom objects, but they can have access to additional applications as long as those applications are sold with an embedded license.

Review this [sheet carefully](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/oem_user_license_comparison.htm)

Comment: Thanks Mohith. Can you please elaborate on "they cannot add anything"? Can they write their own workflow rules, validation rules, custom fields, custom objects, etc? Or not? Or do we have to make these customizations on their behalf? Can we /they install other apps from the AppExchange? What sort of "Admin" access would we have? Is there the Remote access feature that is available to our AppExchange Apps? How simple is it to enable client by client to also gain visibility to optional add on Apps/Objects/Tabs? Is this even possible? Or is it every subscriber (to our Embedded App) sees all.

Comment: OEM apps are like working software and not platform .So i do not think that subscriber org admin can do anything with respect to OEM apps .You can combine OEM and ISVForce both .Refer Trailhead modules https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/isv_plan/isv_plan_app_type

Comment: Your developers can install them apps they need and write workflows and validations .But as a subscriber they have no control over it